# SAS 9.3 passing a variable with spaces to a macro

Tags: sas, sas-macro

I need to pass a variable that contains spaces to a macro. And use this variable to make some logic and to buid a new column inside the macro.

I've tried something like:

```
%MACRO func(var);
    if first.id then &var = 0;
    retain &var;
    if descr = %unquote(%str(%'&var%')) then &var = 1;
%MEND;


proc sort data=work.table5a;
    by id;
run;

data temp;
set work.table5a;
by id;
    %func(PLUTO)
    %func(PAPERINO)
    %func(BANDA BASSOTTI)
if last.id;
run;
```

ERROR is:

NOTE: Line generated by the macro variable "VAR".
37          BANDA BASSOTTI
            _____
            180
ERROR 180-322: Statement is not valid or it is used out of proper order.

If i comment %prova(BANDA BASSOTTI) it works. Any suggestions ?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using &var to create a variable name, and if you want to have a variable name with spaces in it, you need to use the variable name literals, e.g. "BANDA BASSOTTI"n.  I haven't done this myself, seems like it makes the code uglier and harder to write, but something like this seems to work:

```
options validvarname=any;

%MACRO func(var);
    retain "&var"n;
    if first.id then "&var"n = 0;
    if descr = "&var" then "&var"n = 1;
%MEND;
```